# Dropdown in swift with button and UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, dropdown

I wanted to use drop down in my ios app using swift. so far I have achieved everything by watching this video of drop down
[I have created drop down using this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1LiBiLjca4)

but when i print button title

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:IndexPath{ let buttonTitle = btntitle.setTitle("\(fruits[indexpath.row])", for:.normal) print(buttonTitle)}
```

it is displaying --> () <-- in my output.
But I want the selected item name from the code.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: Change `let buttonTitle = btntitle.setTitle("\(fruits[indexpath.row])", for:.normal)` to `let buttonTitle = fruits[indexPath.row]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning the function setTitle (which returns void), to your buttonTitle variable. When you print that variable you're seeing () <- cause it's the empty return.

You probably are seeing a warning on that line.

Modify it like this:

```
let buttonTitle = fruits[indexpath.row]
btntitle.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
```